# ADA type definition in text_io gives warning Item is uninitialized

Tags: ada

I have a type definition

```
type FLOAT_32 is digits 6;
for type FLOAT_32' size use 32;
```

when using in text IO

```
package FLOAT_IO is new Text_IO.Float_IO(Float_32);
```

I get the warning: ITEM is uninitialized.

I'd like to get rid of this warning as I have an INT_32 defined

```
type INTEGER_32 is range - (2**31)..2**31-1;
for type INTEGER_32' size use 32;
```

and the package declaration gives no warnings

```
package INT_IO is new Text_IO.Integer_IO(Integer_32);
```

any help?

EDIT Per the comments:

This is part of a large system - I inherited the code. I cannot post the entire source. the compiler is green hills adamulti 2000.

The type definitions are in a file called System_Types.ads

```
type Boolean_8 is new boolean;
for Boolean_8' use size 8;

type Boolean_16 is new boolean;
for Boolean_16' use size 16;

type Boolean_32 is new boolean;
for Boolean_32' use size 32;

type FLOAT_32 is digits 6;
for type FLOAT_32' size use 32;
type FLOAT_64 is digits 15;
for type FLOAT_64' size use 64;
for type FLOAT_64' alignment use 8;

--INTEGER_2 to Integer_64 is defined here in original
type INTEGER_32 is range - (2**31)..2**31-1;
for type INTEGER_32' size use 32;
```

I will call the source main.adb

```
with System_Types; use System_Types;

package body main is
    package FLOAT_IO is new Text_IO.Float_IO(Float_32);
    package INT_IO is new Text_IO.Integer_IO(Integer_32);
end main
```

I hope this helps

Comment: It would help to tell us what Ada
compiler you're using.  Also, are the above declarations the only things in your program, or is there any other code?  Please post a minimal complete sample that gives you the warning, but that we can try compiling ourselves without having to guess at what other code to add.  Thank you.

Comment: hmmm...it is a very large system that I inherited. the type definitions are in a file system_types.ads, it is included in the source as     "with system_types; use system_types;" the compiler is green hills ada multi 2000. It is difficult to give much more context than that.

Comment: If you don't have an `Item` declared in your program, and it appears that the warning is occurring on the `FLOAT_IO` instantiation, then it looks like Green Hills is responsible for the problem.  It's possible that `Text_IO.Float_IO` is written in Ada, and the compiler is instantiating it by basically recompiling the Ada source of the generic with the generic formals changed to something else.  (That's a popular way to handle generics, but not the only way.)  If that's the case, then GH's own code may have an uninitialized variable in it, in which case there's nothing you can do.

Comment: Thanks ajb - I will see I if I can find that source.